# is there any way to prevent the derived class from initializing a base class reference

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, reference

I have Base and Derived classes, and this code:

```
Derived d; Base& b = d;
```

Is there any cast in this initialization? Сan i theoretically disable this?

Comment: Only by inheriting `Base` privately?

Comment: Inheritance establishes a "`Derived` is-a `Base`" relationship.  If you don't want that relationship, you probably don't want to use inheritance.

Comment: Drew Dormann, just wanted to know is it possible to disable it, in theory.

Comment: There is no cast in that initialization. You can tell just by looking at it. There is an **implicit conversion** to `Base&`.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik , class Derived : public Base

Comment: Why would you want to prevent that (assuming you don't want to follow the advice from Sam or Drew, which would prevent that)?  That is the mechanism by which C++ does polymorphism.

Comment: Eljay, i am studying the syntax of the c++ language, just wondering. 
of course, I can't think of cases in which this might be needed

Comment: In that case, the answers to your questions are simple and straightforward. *Is there any cast in this initialization?* No.  *Сan i theoretically disable this?*  No.

Comment: What do you mean by "cast" in this context? The lvalue `d` will have to undergo type conversion, since you're getting a reference to a different type. Such a conversion might be considered a "cast".

Comment: The variable `d` does not undergo any type conversion. The lvalue `b` will simply reference the part of `d` that is a `B` rvalue. No casting. No coercion. No conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker _There is an implicit conversion to `Base&`_ https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.ref#5.1 doesn't mention any implicit conversions.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer -- thank you for your input; you have utterly missed the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use private inheritance.

```
class derived : private base {};
```